# UIWebView loadHTMLString crashes the app witn EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, uiwebview, exc-bad-access

A screen in my app needs to load embedded YouTube videos. I have it like this:

```
NSString *html = @"<iframe id='ytplayer' type='text/html' width='300' height='390' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/nK8bGHU3d0U?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com' style=\"background-color: #000000;\" frameborder='0'/>"
[self embedYouTube:html frame:CGRectMake(left, 780, 640, 500)];

- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame {    
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:urlString, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
    UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    videoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    videoView.opaque = NO;
    [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:videoView];
}
```

This worked for a time, but suddenly it causes my app to crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I narrowed it down to this line:

```
[videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Also, I know this EXC_BAD_ACCESS is usually an indication for a memory bug, but it doesn't seem to be the case here. I'm not going back and forth to this screen, just hitting it as soon as the app starts. And it crashes.

When I move the app to a different location on my hard disk it works fine. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

That code is not crashing when I run it, so i've no clue about that, it could be just a corrupted cache (have had that multiple times with very odd behaviour). However your code didn't load a video neither, I got it working after making the following change:

Change the first line of your method `embedYouTube:frame:` into:

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"%f\" height=\"%f\" src=\"%@\" allowfullscreen frameborder=\"0\" rel=nofollow></iframe></body></html>", frame.size.width,frame.size.height, urlString];
```

Only pass the source element of the video to the method (just the URL of the video, no HTML), so that would be:

```
[self embedYouTube:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/nK8bGHU3d0U?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com" frame:frame];
```

Comment: Thanks, @Leijonien. How do you mean "corrupted cache"? What did you do to fix it when you had those cache issues?

Comment: Just by deleting the app from the device/simulator, so it has to do a clean install the next time you run the app. (sorry nothing magic ;-)

Comment: Is the behaviour the same with the changes i did, because i tested it out earlier today (your code + 2 lines changed as above), and that worked perfectly...